# Draw flat line on plane in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to draw a lot of flat arrow lines 2d on a plane in three.js. Like navigation map (Google maps). I know about the fat line examples or meshline package. Fat line are not 2d and scale on zoom. The meshline rotate on camera rotation.

Currently I draw an arrow via shape + basicmaterial and place it on the plane. But I wonder, is it really the way to go or is there better solution.

Comment: maybe you can use [CSS2DObject](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/renderers/CSS2DRenderer) to render 2D Lines/Arrows.

Answer (score -1):

If you want very small line you can use pipe geometry for this.

Answer (score -1):

Solution :

```
 const shape = new THREE.Shape();
  shape.moveTo(0, 0);
  shape.lineTo(0, 5);
```

Comment: Yeah that is what I already do. For each line create an arrow shape with couple line.to calls. But is that really the way to go. What about performance. I need to draw about 1000 arrows